# Why the link between .. and the parent dir is hardlink?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, hardlink

I just noticed that the link between .. and the parent dir is hardlink, they have the same inode number:

```
starpinker@host /home/starpinker/unix $ ls -ail
8200794 drwxrwxr-x 2 starpinker starpinker 4096 Aug 23 11:22 .
1409238 drwxrwxr-x 2 starpinker starpinker 4096 Aug 23 11:22 ..
```

where the inode number of `/home/starpinker/unix` is `8200794`, and the inode number of `/home/starpinker` is exactly `1409238`.

I have a question on this:

The hardlink cannot be create across different file systems. Then what if the parent directory and child directory are in different file systems? For example in my case, if the `/home/starpinker` and `/home/starpinker/unix` are in different file system, the unix is just a mount point, then will the link between `/home/starpinker/unix/..` and `/home/starpinker` still be hardlink?

Comment: Apparently so, I just checked with my Windows mount point and it has a normal hard link to the Linux `/` which is `..` for it. Don't know how that works though. If you don't get an answer here after a while, try flagging for migration to [U&L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flora_%28publication%29). The question is on topic on both sites and is more than welcome to stay here, there are just more hard core *nix experts on U&L.

Comment: Thanks, @terdon, Can you revise your link? I follow the U&L link, but it seems incorrect.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com But please don't post the same question there, either flag for migration, or delete this one. Also, as I said before, you can leave it here, it is on topic and there may well be someone who can answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

Why is it a hardlink? Because it points to the parent directory. What else *could* it be, if not a link?

For the filesystem root directory, `..` is *still* a hardlink – but it points to the directory itself, i.e. it's equivalent to `.`. The kernel's VFS layer (which manages mountpoints and filesystems) handles this special case and magically resolves `/home/starpinker/unix/..` to `/home/starpinker` without actually looking at the filesystem.

(Also, I haven't researched this, but I think some filesystems don't really keep the `.` and `..` links on disk, but present emulated ones instead. It wouldn't surprise me if the VFS layer actually did that for all `..` links, not just the special case...)